# Tangent plane to a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $$ f(x,y)= x^4+2y^4+(x-y)^2 $$
and consider the plane $z= ax+by$.

Show that there exists at least one tangent plane to $$ f(x,y)= x^4+2y^4+(x-y)^2 $$ such that it is parallel to $ z= ax+by $.

My idea is to take the difference $$ f(x,y)= x^4+2y^4+(x-y)^2 -(ax+by) $$ and if it has a minimum then it would be a tangent plane there but how can I prove that ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Why downgrade or ask to close this question ? It is a well formed question and there is a little solving attempt by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $f_x(x,y)=4x^3+2(x-y)$, $f_y(x,y)=8y^3-2(x-y)$. Then the the tangent plane at $x_0,y_0$ is given by
$$z=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0).$$
This tangent plane is parallel to $z=ax+by$ iff the system
$$4x_0^3+2(x_0-y_0)=f_x(x_0,y_0)=a, \quad 8y_0^3-2(x_0-y_0)=f_y(x_0,y_0)=b$$
has at least a solution $(x_0,y_0)$.

From the first equation we get $y_0=(4x_0^3+2x_0-a)/2$. Then, by replacing $y_0$ in the second equation, we obtain a polynomial in $x_0$ of degree 9. Since the degree is odd, it has at least one real root. Therefore the system is solvable.